# Change the color for the company text field

Tags: jquery, html, css

User table

```
user_ID       user_type       user_company
   1              I
```

user_type: 
 I - internal 
 E - external

updateuser.php

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="js/jquery-ui-themes-1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    //---CLICK USER TYPE RADIO BUTTON---
    $(".usertype").click(function() 
    {
        if($(this).val() === 'I')
        {
            $("#usercompanyname").val('');
            $("#usercompanyname").attr('disabled', true);
            $("#usercompanyname").css("background-color", "gray");
        }
        else 
        {
            $("#usercompanyname").attr('disabled', false);
            $("#usercompanyname").css("background-color", "skyblue");
        }
    });   
});
</script>
<style>
.staffcompanyfieldcellinput {
background-color: skyblue; 
color: blue;
}

.staffcompanydisablefieldcellinput {
background-color: gray; 
color: blue; 
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<form method="post" action="user.php">
  <table>
  <?php
  //---DB Connect---
  $query = "SELECT *
            FROM user 
            WHERE user_ID = 1"; 
  $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
  $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
  ?>
  <tr>
    <td> Type : <span class="style2">*</span></td>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" name="usertype" class="usertype" value="I"
      <?php if($row['user_type'] == 'I') echo 'checked'; ?> />Internal
      <input type="radio" name="usertype" class="usertype" value="E" 
      <?php if($row['user_type'] == 'E') echo 'checked'; ?> />External
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Company Name : </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="usercompanyname" id="usercompanyname"   value="<?php echo $row['user_company']; ?>" 
      maxlength="120" size="40" <?php echo ($row['user_type'] == 'I') ? 'class="usercompanydisablefieldcellinput" disabled' : 
      'class="usercompanyfieldcellinput"'; ?> />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update User"></td>
    <td><input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

My condition is like this:
- If user choose Internal, the company text field will be disable with gray color.
- If user choose External, the company text field will be enable with skyblue color.

From above code, I will get the disable company text field with gray color. 
Now I want change to External. When I change to External, the company text field will enable with skyblue color and let me to fill in.
 My only problem is when I click the reset button, the user type radio button will change to Internal, but the company text field color still remain to skyblue color not the gray color and the text field was also not disable.
 How should I modify it? Can someone help me?

Comment: Maybe you could call a javascript function when pressing reset that will modify the text field and radio button